# Reduce memory usage while read data from datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-management, datatable

I have tried this way to read data from data table  is there any other better way to store data in list (to reduce memory usage ).

Code :

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    Myclassdef data = new Myclassdef();
    data.Data = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (DataColumn columninfo in table.Columns)
    {
        object value = row[columninfo.ColumnName];
        Myclassdef.Data.Add(columninfo.ColumnName, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your memory problem is caused by the `DataTable`? You are mapping all into a custom class with a dictionary for every row. So you're required memory is more than twice than with the `DataTable` alone. Why don't you use a `DataReader` to read those values from database? That streams the data without needing to store anything in memory.

Comment: @TimSchmelter how to avoid more than take meemory as twice

Comment: @Smith: Use my `DataReader` approach below if the source of the data is a database. Then the `Myclassdef` instancers with their   dictionaries are the only memory consumers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : whether it occur any error or anything if more than user access the database in the same time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure your memory problem is caused by the `DataTable`? You are mapping all into a custom class with a dictionary for every row. So you're required memory is more than twice than with the `DataTable` alone.

However, if you are reading the values from database and you are loading all into a `DataTable` first just to be able to loop all to create your custom class with the dictionary, then there is a better way in terms of memory consumption:

- use a `DataReader` to read those values from database. That streams the data without needing to store anything in memory

  ```
  var list = new List<Myclassdef>();
  using (var con = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
  {
      using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ... WHERE Col1=@param1", con))
      {
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", "value1");
          // ...
          con.Open();
          using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
          {
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                  Myclassdef data = new Myclassdef();
                  data.Data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                  for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                  {
                      data.Data.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader[i]);
                  }
                  list.Add(data);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: whether it occur any error or anything if more than user access the database in the same time

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking if there's a better approach or are you asking if there's a more efficient memory storage option?

I'm very skeptical any other memory storage option is going to give you a noticeable difference. Lists and Dictionary may not be the most efficient storage option but they're not hogs either.

If you want to know if there's a better approach that depends on what you're trying to do. If this data is to be displayed to the user typically what's done is the visible size of the table is calculated (so that the scroll bars behave as expected) and only some of the immediately previous and next records just out of the viewing area are cached. As the user moves around looking at the table the data is lazy loaded as needed.